# Z-index rendering links unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My negative z-index is causing the links to be unclickable even though there are no other elements above it. I can't figure out what is causing the issue. I've removed all other elements on the page and it still exists happens. What is covering the links?

```css
#scrollingdiv {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.boxes {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index:-2;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='scrollingdiv'>


  <div style='margin-top:40px'></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
<br/><a href='#'>link</a>


</div>
```

Comment: The divs named "boxes" should be classes, not id.

Comment: Why use a negative z-index? Give `.boxes` a z-index of 1, and then for elements that you want to stack above it, use values greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Just add a wrapper around the .boxes and add overflow: scroll; and height to it :)

```css
#scrollingdiv {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;  
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.boxes-wrap{
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 150px;
}
#banner {  
  width: 5000px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  /* z-index:-1; */
}
.boxes {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  /* z-index:-2;
  position:relative; */
}
```

```html
<div id='scrollingdiv'>


  <div id='banner'>HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER</div>

<div class="boxes-wrap">   
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
  <div class='boxes'>box<br/><a href='#'>link</a></div>
<br/><a href='#'>link</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It needs to be positioned within the div, there is content above the scrolling div

Comment: So #baner just needs to be on top of the boxes? Then the boxes need to be inside another div that will have the scroll functionality. Like you have it it will not stay on top :) And position fixed makes the element fixed in relation to the page not the div :) I will make some adjustments now to my answer :)

Comment: @danielb Check the updated answer and let me know if that is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not limited to `a` elements.  You'll have the same problem if you change them to buttons.  Basically, you can see elements with a negative z-index, but you *cannot* interact with them.  (See **http://jsfiddle.net/bhxem01j/1/** for an example using buttons.)

A quick fix may be to apply a z-index to all elements, then a smaller (but non-negative) z-index to `.boxes`:

```
* {
  ...
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.boxes {
  ...
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Since `z-index` applies to positioned elements only, I added `position: relative` to the `*` styles.